# Testing an AJAX API that uses session authentication with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a restful API provided by Django and Tastypie protected with SessionAuthentication and  DjangoAuthorization. How can I get Jasmine to authenticate or step through the login page before each API test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasmin is a unit test framework. In unit test you should test your units without the need of external dependencies. So you shouldn't run your unit test again a real API. Mock out your API with [sinon server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer).

If you wanna run test with your real side and real API you should choose a integration test framework like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [CapserJS](http://casperjs.org/)